# JsViews: Update/refresh data on multiple `select's` dynamically simultaneously - using depends=

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

I am having trouble getting observable data to update/refresh on multiple `select's` dynamically simultaneously.

When rendering two+ `select's` with a filter displaying only those `option's` that are NOT selected in another `select`. Thus, if an option is selected in one `select` that same option should not appear in the other `select's`.

...on initial page load, the options are filtered correctly.

...on `select` change, the options do not re-filter correctly, I think because the options are filtered before the data value is updated (but I'm not sure they would all refresh anyway).

```
{^{for selectedVals ~selectedVals=selectedVals ~listVals=listVals}}
     <select data-link="id">
        {^{for ~catFilter(id, ~listVals, ~selectedVals)}}
            <option data-link="value{:id} {:category}"></option>
        {{/for}}
    </select>
{{/for}}
```

```
$.views.helpers({
     catFilter: function(id, listVals, selectedVals) {
          return listVals.filter(item1 =>
              !selectedVals.some(item2 => (item2.id) === item1.id && item1.id !== id));
     }
})
```

I'm not quite sure the best approach to this and have tried using the built in `filter=... mapDepends="id"`, `convertBack`...with little success.

Now I am listening for changes observably and refreshing the array...but It's not working (not sure if I am doing this right).

```
$(data[0].selectedVals).on("propertyChange", changeHandler)
function changeHandler(ev, eventArgs) {
     $.observable(data[0].selectedVals).refresh(data[0].selectedVals)
}
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alnico/tr6wfn13/

Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that would be not to try to trigger arrayChange events on the data, but rather to make just the contents of the `{^{for ~catFilter(id, ~listVals, ~selectedVals)}}` tag refresh whenever one of the `selectedVals` items has an observable change to its `id`.

You can do that by specifying a `depends` property on your `~catFilter()` helper function (see [Declaring dependencies for a computed observable](https://www.jsviews.com/#computed@depends)), or on the `{^{for}}` tag itself.

In fact your 'depends' path can use the wild card `.[]` which lets you listen to a given property on any item within an array. In your case it will be `depends = "~selectedVals.[].id"` - which will listen only to changes in an `id` property on an item in the array, and will trigger refresh on the content of the `{^{for ...}}` tag.

That `.[]` wild card is lacking detailed documentation (I hope to add it at some point) but you can see it used in samples such as [here](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/sort-filter@jsv-for).

There are two ways you can add that dependency:

Declaratively on the `{^{for}}` tag:

```
{^{for ~catFilter(id, ~listVals, ~selectedVals) depends="~selectedVals.[].id"}}
```

or programmatically on the observable helper function:

```
$.views.helpers.catFilter.depends = "~selectedVals.[].id";
```

The same approach can be used if you set a `filter=...` function on your `{^{for}}` tag rather than using a computed helper to filter. You simply specify the depends property on your filter function:

```
{^{for ~listVals filter=~listFilter}}
  <option data-link="value{:id} {:category}"></option>
{{/for}}
```

with the helper:

```
listFilter: function(item1) {
  return !this.ctxPrm("selectedVals").some(
    item2 => (item2.id) === item1.id && item1.id !== this.view.data.id
  );
}
```

and then either add the `depends="~selectedVals.[].id"` to the tag (as with the `catFilter()` version), or set it on the listFilter function, like this:

```
$.views.helpers.listFilter.depends = "~selectedVals.[].id";
```

Here is a [version of your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/x2cu671r/3/) showing these alternative approaches.

Comment: Excellent!  Initially I tried using mapDepends...but I was a little off ;-)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the many different options. I learned so much here. I am glad I asked! Thank you